Issues installing portmaster on fedora kinoite
I'm trying to install safing's portmaster on fedora kinoite using the rpm file given on the website https://safing.io/ and rpm-ostree, this appears to be successful but when I restart portmaster shows up in my applications but will not start, running
journalctl -u portmaster gives the following output:
Aug 06 23:39:30 fedora systemd[1]: Started portmaster.service - Portmaster by Safing.
Aug 06 23:39:31 fedora portmaster-start[16605]: Error: failed to exec lock: open /opt/safing/portmaster/core-lock.p>
Aug 06 23:39:31 fedora systemd[1]: portmaster.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 06 23:39:31 fedora portmaster-start[16668]: Error: please set the data directory using --data=/path/to/data/dir
Aug 06 23:39:31 fedora systemd[1]: portmaster.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

I cannot understand why this is as according to a discussion for fedora silverblue https://github.com/safing/portmaster-packaging/issues/56 (which like kinoite is an immutable fedora spin only using the gnome desktop rather than KDE):
"
Thanks for the pointers!

    silver blue is mostly immutable

Ah, yes. That would be a problem. But /opt seems to linked to /var/opt now, so maybe this isn't a problem after all.
"

Kinoite appears to be following the same practice so I cannot work out why portmaster is failing to get a lock.
Can you please let me know how to fix this and/or what is going on here? Thanks
